# Why does joining 5 threads at once result in simultaneous activity?

Tags: ruby, multithreading

```
Thread.new{sleep rand(0..10}; puts '#1 done'}.join
Thread.new{sleep rand(0..10}; puts '#2 done'}.join
Thread.new{sleep rand(0..10}; puts '#3 done'}.join
Thread.new{sleep rand(0..10}; puts '#4 done'}.join
Thread.new{sleep rand(0..10}; puts '#5 done'}.join
```

This will result in thread 1 being executed to completion before thread 2 begins. I will always get the output 1-2-3-4-5 and the batch can take up to 50 seconds.

```
t1 = Thread.new {sleep rand(0..10); puts 'Thread 1 done.'}
t2 = Thread.new {sleep rand(0..10); puts 'Thread 2 done.'}
t3 = Thread.new {sleep rand(0..10); puts 'Thread 3 done.'}
t4 = Thread.new {sleep rand(0..10); puts 'Thread 4 done.'}
t5 = Thread.new {sleep rand(0..10); puts 'Thread 5 done.'}
[t1,t2,t3,t4,t5].map(&:join)
```

This, however, results in all 5 threads being executed in parallel; each time I will get a random output order and the entire batch takes no more than 10 seconds.

My question is: Why?

My understanding is that `map` will go through each item in the array and execute the `Thread#join` method on each one in turn... which is exactly what my first code example does. So I would expect totally identical results, yet there's clearly some difference there.

Comment: Why what? It's not clear which side is confusing you. The first example executes (start thread, join thread, start thread, join thread, ...) - the second example executes (start thread, start thread, ..., join thread, join thread, ...).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My understanding is that map will go through each item in the array and execute the Thread#join method on each one in turn... which is exactly what my first code example does.

No, it isn't.

The first code starts a thread, then joins it - and *then* starts the next thread, joins it, etc. There's no parallelism involved:

```
Start thread 1
Join thread 1
Start thread 2
Join thread 2
Start thread 3
Join thread 3
Start thread 4
Join thread 4
Start thread 5
Join thread 5
```

The second code starts *all* the threads, then joins *all* of them. So when the first `join` call is executed, all the threads are running, rather than just the one extra one.

```
Start thread 1
Start thread 2
Start thread 3
Start thread 4
Start thread 5
Join thread 1
Join thread 2
Join thread 3
Join thread 4
Join thread 5
```

Do you understand why those are different?

Comment: So does instantiating the Thread class actually trigger some kind of behaviour, beyond simply storing the given block for later execution? It seems like that was my faulty assumption. Does `join` trigger execution of the thread (as I assumed) or simply wait for the thread to finish?

Comment: @GreenTriangle: Yes, `Thread.new` starts the thread, and `Thread.join` *just* waits for the thread to finish.